# setting HTML table column width

Tags: html, css

I've got a simple table.

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Preview</th>
        </tr>
```

How do I set the width so the Select and Preview be 15px and Name be rest of the width left ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey now you can define in your css as like this

**Css**

```
   .some{
    width:15px;
    }
```

HTML

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
                <th class="some">Select</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th  class="some">Preview</th>
        </tr>
</table>
```

live demo
http://tinkerbin.com/n4Q1NOXW

Answer (score 1):

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
                <th width="15">Select</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th width="15">Preview</th>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use as

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
        <th width="15px">Select</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th width="15px">Preview</th>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1px" width="100%">
   <tr>
        <th width="15px">Select</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th width="15px">Preview</th>
   </tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

If you want to preview in any size screen according to their size, use '%' to determine the size. For ex

```
<table border="1px" width="100%">
   <tr>
        <th width="15%">Select</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th width="15%">Preview</th>
   </tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```